# How to install ursa in ubuntu machine

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, npm-install

i am trying to install ursa on ubuntu machine but have a problem.

the version of node i am running is:
    - node -v v10.4.1
    - node-gyp -v v3.6.2

I cannot figure out the error from the err stack:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: make failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node- 
gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:237:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1060-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" 
"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" 
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/buze-payments/node_modules/ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v10.4.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN ms-payments@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ursa@0.9.4 install: node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ursa@0.9.4 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-06-14T21_53_02_279Z-debug.log
```

Any idea where could be the problem?

Comment: did you verify that you have `libssl-dev` installed ? `apt-get install libssl-dev` it's described [here](https://github.com/JoshKaufman/ursa/issues/12)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
If you do have the `libssl-dev` install and still have the issue, try to downgrade node ... Not ideal but it does the trick for me.

I used [`n`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) to manage my version of node.

After installing the version `8.11.3` `ursa` installed perfectly.